# Help for applying Hahn Banach theorem in this exercise .

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I want to use this version of Hahn Banach:

> $X$ real vector space, $M$ a subspace, $p$ a sub-linear mapping and $T:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ linear and $T(x)\leq p(x)$ $\forall x \in M$
>
> Then $\exists$ an extension of $T$ to whole X. And $\hat{T}\leq p(x) \quad\forall x\in X$.

In our exercise

$M=C:=\{(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty \quad x_i\in \mathbb{R}: \exists \lim_{i\to\infty} x_i\} $

$X=l_\infty:=\{(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty \quad x_i\in \mathbb{R}:\exists \sup\{|x_i|: i\in\mathbb{N}\}$

We have proved that $$p(x):=\limsup_{i\to\infty}x_i:=\lim_{i\to\infty}\sup\{x_j:j\geq i\}$$ is a sub-linear mapping.

our $T:=\lim$, $T(x):C\to\mathbb{R}$, $T(x):=\lim_{i\to\infty}x_i$

So for being able to apply the theorem we need to check this:

$$T(x)\leq p(x)\quad\forall x\in C$$

$$T(x):=\lim_{i\to\infty}x_i$$

we have $$\forall i\quad x_i\leq \sup\{x_j:j\geq i\}$$

so $$T(x):=\lim_{i\to\infty}x_i\leq \lim_{i\to\infty}\sup\{x_j:j\geq i\}=:p(x)$$

(Note 1: is the argument of  above inequality  correct? )

So now we are able to apply the theorem and we have:

$$\exists \quad \hat{T}:l_{\infty}:\to\mathbb{R}$$ linear mapping and $\hat{T}$ is an extension of $T$.

The exercise have more question:

A) Show that $$\liminf_{i\to\infty} x_i\leq \hat{T}(x)\leq \limsup_{i\to\infty}x_i\quad\forall x\in l_\infty$$

Here the second part of the inequality is guaranteed by the theorem. But how do we prove the first inequality?

B) Is $$\hat{T}( (x_i)_{i=1}^\infty )=\hat{T}((x_{i+1})_{i=1}^\infty)\quad \forall x \in l_{\infty} ?$$

Comment: Re A), consider $-x$. $\hat{T}(-x) \leqslant \limsup (-x_i)$. Re B), not necessarily.

Comment: Using $\hat{T}(-x)=-\hat{T}(x)\leq \limsup (-x_i)$, since $\hat{T}$ is linear, and  multiplying  by a negative number change the inequality so we have $\hat{T}(x)\geq \limsup(x_i)$. But how can I continue to relate with $\liminf(x_i)$?

Comment: In general, $-\limsup (-x_i) \neq \limsup x_i$. It has something to do with $\liminf$ instead.

Comment: Ok, we have $\hat{T}(-x)=-\hat{T}(x)\leq \limsup (-x_i)=-\liminf(x_i)$, so we have $\liminf(x_i)\leq \hat{T}(x)$.

Some hint for B)? please

Comment: Re B), consider the space $A = \{ x\in \ell^\infty : \lim x_{2n} \text{ exists}, \lim x_{2n+1} \text{ exists}\}$.

Comment: Yes, haha  I deleted the comment as fast as I realized the mistake when I  tried to do the proof in a paper but you answer was faster

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11369/discussion-between-user102800-and-daniel-fischer)